# I want to remove all contents of %temp% directory wihout any confirmation

Tags: windows, powershell

I just want to delete `%temp%` folder of that particular user that is currently logged in without any confirmation using a PowerShell script.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$tempRM = @("C:\Users*\Appdata\Local\Temp*") 
Remove-Item -Path $tempRM -Recurse -Force
```

OS will be mostly server 2003,2008,2012 and above.

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work as expected?

Comment: $tempRM = @("C:\Users\*\Appdata\Local\Temp\*")
Remove-Item -Path $tempRM -Recurse -Force    this always gives access denied error on my windows 10 machine and if I use it in 2012 server it show a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$env:TEMP` environment variable to determine the *temp* path and delete it using the `Remove-Item` cmdlet with the `-ErrorAction` parameter set to `SilentlyContinue` to supress any potential errors:

```
Remove-Item -Path $env:TEMP -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: will it support 2003 server

Comment: Most likely yes but didn't tested it.